# Pyomo, Exiting pyomo solve: Multiple models defined in file:

Tags: pyomo

Working on my first pyomo lp and I am having trouble when I go to load the data. The model appears to be fine but then when it goes to solve it returns that all of my variables are stale and will not give me any values. I have some ideas but wanted to get some more to see if someone else could point out what I am doing wrong. Below is the model

```
from pyomo.environ import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyomo.core import *

opt = AbstractModel()


opt.PC = Set()
opt.DC = Set()
opt.costs =Param(opt.PC,opt.DC, within = NonNegativeReals)
opt.demands=Param(opt.DC, within = NonNegativeIntegers)
opt.supply= Param(opt.PC, within = NonNegativeIntegers)
opt.cases = Var(opt.PC,opt.DC,domain = NonNegativeIntegers)

def constraint1(opt,DC):
    return sum(
     opt.cases[i,DC]
     for i in opt.PC 
     ) == opt.demands[DC]   
opt.constraintdemand = Constraint(opt.DC,rule = constraint1)


def constraint2(opt,PC):
    return sum(
     opt.cases[PC,j]
     for j in opt.DC
     ) <= opt.supply[PC]
opt.constraintsupply = Constraint(opt.PC,rule = constraint2)


def ObjectiveFunction(opt):
     return sum(
       opt.costs[i,j] * opt.cases[i,j]
        for i in opt.PC
        for j in opt.DC

)

opt.Obj=Objective(rule=ObjectiveFunction)

data = DataPortal()
data.load(filename='lp.dat', set = opt.PC)
data.load(filename ='lp.dat', set = opt.DC)
data.load(filename='lp.dat', param = opt.costs)
data.load(filename='lp.dat', param = opt.demands)
data.load(filename='lp.dat', param = opt.supply)

instance = opt.create_instance(data)
instance.pprint()
```

Here are are the variable declarations:

```
1 Var Declarations
    cases : Size=288, Index=cases_index
        Key      : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
          (1, 1) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
          (1, 2) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
          (1, 3) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
          (1, 4) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
          (1, 5) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
          (1, 6) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
          (1, 7) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
          (1, 8) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
          (1, 9) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 10) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 11) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 12) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 13) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 14) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 15) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 16) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 17) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 18) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 19) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 20) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 21) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 22) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 23) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 24) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 25) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 26) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 27) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 28) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 29) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 30) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 31) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 32) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 33) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 34) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 35) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 36) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 37) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 38) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 39) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 40) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 41) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 42) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 43) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 44) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 45) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 46) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 47) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 48) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 49) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 50) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 51) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 52) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 53) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 54) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 55) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 56) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 57) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 58) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 59) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 60) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 61) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 62) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 63) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 64) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 65) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 66) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 67) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 68) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 69) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 70) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 71) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 72) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 73) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 74) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 75) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 76) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 77) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 78) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 79) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 80) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 81) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 82) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 83) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 84) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 85) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 86) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 87) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 88) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 89) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 90) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 91) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 92) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 93) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 94) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 95) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 96) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 97) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 98) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (1, 99) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 100) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 101) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 102) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 103) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 104) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 105) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 106) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 107) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 108) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 109) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 110) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 111) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 112) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 113) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 114) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 115) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 116) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 117) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 118) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 119) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 120) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 121) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 122) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 123) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 124) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 125) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 126) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 127) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 128) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 129) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 130) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 131) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 132) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 133) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 134) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 135) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 136) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 137) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 138) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 139) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 140) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 141) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 142) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 143) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (1, 144) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
          (2, 1) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
          (2, 2) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
          (2, 3) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
          (2, 4) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
          (2, 5) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
          (2, 6) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
          (2, 7) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
          (2, 8) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
          (2, 9) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 10) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 11) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 12) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 13) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 14) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 15) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 16) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 17) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 18) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 19) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 20) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 21) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 22) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 23) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 24) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 25) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 26) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 27) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 28) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 29) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 30) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 31) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 32) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 33) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 34) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 35) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 36) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 37) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 38) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 39) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 40) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 41) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 42) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 43) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 44) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 45) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 46) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 47) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 48) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 49) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 50) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 51) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 52) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 53) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 54) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 55) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 56) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 57) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 58) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 59) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 60) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 61) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 62) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 63) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 64) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 65) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 66) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 67) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 68) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 69) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 70) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 71) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 72) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 73) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 74) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 75) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 76) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 77) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 78) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 79) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 80) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 81) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 82) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 83) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 84) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 85) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 86) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 87) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 88) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 89) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 90) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 91) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 92) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 93) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 94) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 95) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 96) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 97) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 98) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
         (2, 99) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 100) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 101) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 102) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 103) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 104) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 105) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 106) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 107) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 108) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 109) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 110) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 111) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 112) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 113) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 114) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 115) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 116) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 117) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 118) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 119) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 120) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 121) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 122) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 123) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 124) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 125) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 126) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 127) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 128) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 129) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 130) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 131) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 132) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 133) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 134) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 135) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 136) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 137) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 138) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 139) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 140) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 141) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 142) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 143) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
        (2, 144) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeIntegers
```

Comment: Could you include the line you're using to solve the model?

Comment: pyomo solve LPModel2.py --solver=glpk is command I am using in the terminal to execute

Comment: It appears that there maybe an issue with the way I am using the dataportal method, I just removed that code and just had my dat file in the command line with my py file and got an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you were combining two ways of solving Pyomo models that aren't compatible. If you start with an abstract model you can solve it by:

1. In a Python script use a `DataPortal` to create a concrete model instance and then solve that model by using the `SolverFactory` to call a solver
2. Use the `pyomo` command and pass in the Python script defining the abstract model and a `.dat` file with the data to instantiate the model

Comment: Thank you Bethany!